# Sure you're not looking for /faye ? showing on heroku for my chatt application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

A simple chat demo application i have deployed on heroku but it show me 'Sure you're not looking for /faye ?' instead of running application..
**`I have gem structure as :`**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "private_pub"
gem "thin"

gem 'devise'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'


gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails'
 gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
   gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.0'
end
group :development do
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'sqlite3'

end

group :production do
 gem 'rails_12factor'
 gem 'pg'

end
```

**

- ### And my Procfile that i am trying to run on heroku:

web: bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -p $PORT -E production

**::::privat_pub.yml file :**

```
development:
  server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "secret"
test:
  server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "secret"
production:
  server: "http://chatmanoj.herokuapp.com/faye"
  secret_token: "fa3a4537eb321521a40fce4fa4d7bb055436e1f6ba5e74a3c85ec683c5abe997"
  signature_expiration: 3600 # one hour
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm in the same boat right now.